# Is there a way to specify certs/Key content in stunnel configuration

Tags: stunnel

I have a requirement where in I cannot specify the certificate and/or private key details as "files" to stunnel configuration, owing to the location and/or file system availability for stunnel to access them.

Is there a way to specify the actual certificate content in stunnel configuration (similar to other parameters like port numbers etc.,) so that the same can be leveraged.